# SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, utf-8, seeding

I'm having this problem while seeding my PGSQL Database:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERROR:  secuencia de bytes no válida para codificación «UTF8»: 0xe3 0x83 0xe2 (SQL: insert into "races" ("name", "public_name", "members", "updated_at", "created_at") values (harp��a, HarpÃ­a, 23, 2018-04-21 20:30:20, 2018-04-21 20:30:20) returning "id")

  at C:\Sandbox\rpgforum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERROR:  secuencia de bytes no válida para codificación «UTF8»: 0xe3 0x83 0xe2")
      C:\Sandbox\rpgforum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:330

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\Sandbox\rpgforum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:330

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

And this is my Seeder's code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Race;

class RaceTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

      $races = [
        'Humano',
        'Orco',
        'Elfo',
        'Harpía',
        'Enano',
      ];

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($races); $i++) {

        $race_i = utf8_encode($races[$i]);

        $race = Race::create([
          'name' => strtolower($race_i),
          'public_name' => $race_i,
          'members' => mt_rand(10,30),
        ]);

      } // for

    }
}
```

My database configuration:

[pgsql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcjn9.png)

My config.database file config:

[config.database file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEzCc.png)

Is there any solution for this problem? I can find the way to get rid of this problem...

**EDIT:**

I just noticed something weird. I got two records in my database:

[database records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFOiL.png)

And both of them have symbols that gave me problem with the **seeder**. Maybe the problem is within the seeders logic? I'm doing the exact same thing I do the whole time with my Laravel/Postgresql projects so i can't find the reason why i can't seed words with accent mark but i can use a simple form to store that kind of information. Any ideas ?

Comment: Your `Harpía` has a funny i. I'm pretty sure that's your problem.

Comment: Yes i know. That's because i'm from a spanish speaking country and my application would serve people who speaks spanish. I need those accent marks on certain words.

Comment: What encoding is your database? HTML page? Application? Make it all UTF-8, problem solved, no need to `utf8_encode`, these characters are supported out of the box.

Comment: Look at the images i added. I've configure everything to UTF8 and i do not have a html file because right now i'm focused on the database.

Comment: What happens if you don't wrap the `$races[i]` in `utf8_encode()`?

Comment: The same mistake, that was an attempt to solve my problem.

Comment: What is the file encoding? Are you sure it is UTF-8? And the client connection? There obviously a conversion happening somewhere. Either your file is not UTF-8 or client connection is not UTF-8.

Comment: @AleksanderWons Which file are you talking about? And how can i determine if my client conecction is set to UTF-8 ?

Comment: The file where those strings you are trying to add are. PHP assumes every string is UTF-8 encoded. If a file containing a string is not UTF-8 it can lead to similar errors. To set client encoding use `pg_set_client_encoding`.